# Does the phrase "as long as" mean while in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, synonyms

The person in question is hypnotized. Two other people are talking about that person. One of them wants that man out of his apartment and he says to his friend:

"Get him out **as long as** the trance is lasting?"

Does the phrase "as long as" is the synonym for the word while here? Could they be used interchangeably? (I've heard somewhere that it can)

TFD def for "as long as"

1. During the time that: I'll stay as long as you need me.

Comment: Can you share some more context? This seems like it could be a conditional (i.e. we could substitute "provided that" for "as long as"). Also, is there truly supposed to be a question mark at the end? It seems like more of a statement, unless the first speaker has e.g. said "What should we do with him?" and the second speaker is not sure..

Comment: It looks like *while* can be substituted. It seems like the idea is to get the other guy out of (the room?) while he is in a trance so that he doesn't notice whom is moving him or where he is being moved to. More context would be necessary to confirm.

Comment: Yes, more context would help. Technical meaning here seems to be covered over by the conversation. The speaker seems to be using "as long as" in the form of since or because. "(It is convenient to) get him out as long as (because) he is in the trance."   There is a fairy standard comedy thing that patterns this way. Person A causes person B to trip. Person B winds up with his face on the floor right by the couch. "As long as I'm down here, I will pull this fork from under the couch."

Comment: Another way of expressing that *since* or *because* is *given that...*